# Which methods are available to programmatically add XO Triggers?

Tags: experience-optimization, sites-9.1, external-integrations, .net

We are looking to add Triggers to XO Programmatically.

I found this question that refers to ST 2014 and how to do this:
[How to create Custom Trigger in SmartTarget 2014 SP1](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11071/how-to-create-custom-trigger-in-smarttarget-2014-sp1)

However, I was interested to know if the options have changed in SDL Tridion Sites 9.1.  I can see that there are now Powershell scripts that we can execute to create new triggers:  https://docs.sdl.com/783502/672996/sdl-tridion-sites-9-1/managing-trigger-types-with-cmdlets

I'm wondering if there are any other methods.  For example, lets say we created an add-on that put a button in the ribbon bar of the Tridion GUI.  When this button is clicked, it would trigger some .NET code to parse a JSON file sitting on the file system and create the Triggers.

Would the .NET code need to trigger the Powershell scripts to create the triggers or is there a better option?

Comment: Nicholas, any update on this did you find any solution